# How to extract milliseconds data from timestamp and find the average of its data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am in a tricky situation on solving the timeseries data. Let me try to explain using the following table

```
       T1                   D1      T2(roundup ms)     D2(avg of D1)   T3(round up ms)     D3     T4(roundup to second)  D4(avg second)

2020.05.22 11.30.1.200      10
2020.05.22 11.30.1.220      20
2020.05.22 11.30.1.240      30
2020.05.22 11.30.1.260      40
2020.05.22 11.30.1.280      50      2020.05.22 11.30.1.200    30
2020.05.22 11.30.1.300      60
2020.05.22 11.30.1.310      70
2020.05.22 11.30.1.350      80      2020.05.22 11.30.1.300    70
2020.05.22 11.30.1.400      90
2020.05.22 11.30.1.450      11
2020.05.22 11.30.1.470      31      2020.05.22 11.30.1.400    44     2020.05.22 11.30.1    48     
................
2020.05.22 11.30.7.100      22
2020.05.22 11.30.7.120      33
2020.05.22 11.30.7.140      44
2020.05.22 11.30.7.160      55
2020.05.22 11.30.7.180      66      2020.05.22 11.30.7.100    44
2020.05.22 11.30.7.200      77
2020.05.22 11.30.7.210      88
2020.05.22 11.30.7.250      99      2020.05.22 11.30.7.200    88
2020.05.22 11.30.7.300      31
2020.05.22 11.30.7.350      32
2020.05.22 11.30.7.370      33      2020.05.22 11.30.7.300    32     2020.05.22 11.30.7    54.66   2020.05.22 11.30
................
```

I import a timeseries data from csv file. On the first level, I want to find the average of the data in the millisecond part(between 0-100,100-200 etc) and round the millisecond value. On the second level, i want to average the values further on the millisecond (average 100,200,300 etc). I want to keep averaging to seconds (1 sec,2 sec,3 sec etc) and round up the time stamp to seconds place. Not sure how to explain, but the table tries to depict the situation. Feel free to down vote me, but i am lost as to how to achieve this averaging.

The logic i guess would be to first select the millisecond part, say between 0-100 millisecond, average all the values between these two points and round the millisecond value as 1. Do the same for every other millisecond and continue forward for 2nd and 3rd level
I am lost. Just a direction would also help on selecting values between milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below a solution to your problem. I tackled the problem using dates as string, but I think it can be done if we just use datetime format (I will think about it). I took portion of the data I am able to see in the example above and was able to build your expected results. Feel free to reach out if you have questions. I hope this helps.

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_folder, file_name)) # here I am just reading your file, portion you provided in the question
df["T1"] = df["T1"].astype(str) # will work on the time, but in the form of a string
df.sort_values("T1", inplace=True)
df["hour"] = df["T1"].map(lambda s: ".".join(s.split(".")[:3])) # separating hour portion
df["minute"] = df["T1"].map(lambda s: ".".join(s.split(".")[:4])) # separating minute portion
df["second"] = df["T1"].map(lambda s: ".".join(s.split(".")[:5])) # separating second portion
df["mili"] = df["T1"].map(lambda s: s.split(".")[-1]).astype(int) # separating milisecond portion
df["mili"] = (df["mili"].values // 100) * 100 # rounding down the milisecond
df["milisecond"] = df["second"] + "." + df["mili"].astype(str)
df["miliRowID"] = df.groupby("milisecond").cumcount() + 1 # creating a row count for miliseconds, need this to join data back together
df["secRowID"] = df.groupby("second").cumcount() + 1  # creating a row count for seconds
df["minRowID"] = df.groupby("minute").cumcount() + 1  # creating a row count for minutes
df.drop(["mili"], axis=1, inplace=True)

xMili = df.groupby("milisecond")["D1"].mean().reset_index() # calculating milisecond averages
xMili.columns = ["T2(roundup ms)", "D2(avg of D1)"]

xSec = df.groupby("second")["D1"].mean().reset_index() # calculating second averages
xSec.columns = ["T3(round up ms)", "D3"]

xMin = df.groupby("minute")["D1"].mean().reset_index() # calculating minute averages
xMin.columns = ["T4(roundup to second)", "D4(avg second)"]

# in this section we are joining calculated averages back with the main dataframe
dfTemp = df.groupby("milisecond")["miliRowID"].max().reset_index().merge(xMili, 
                                                                     how="left", 
                                                                     left_on="milisecond", 
                                                                     right_on="T2(roundup ms)")
df = df.merge(dfTemp, how="left", on=["milisecond", "miliRowID"])

dfTemp = df.groupby("second")["secRowID"].max().reset_index().merge(xSec, 
                                                                how="left", 
                                                                left_on="second", 
                                                                right_on="T3(round up ms)")
df = df.merge(dfTemp, how="left", on=["second", "secRowID"])

dfTemp = df.groupby("minute")["minRowID"].max().reset_index().merge(xMin, 
                                                                how="left", 
                                                                left_on="minute", 
                                                                right_on="T4(roundup to second)")
df = df.merge(dfTemp, how="left", on=["minute", "minRowID"])
# and finally dropping unnecessary columns
DROP = ["hour", "minute", "second", "milisecond", "miliRowID", "secRowID", "minRowID"]
df.drop(DROP, axis=1, inplace=True)
```